# Menu in android

Tags: android, button, menu

I can see in most application a bar in the page top with the page heading in the left and menu in the right. And gets a menu with aligned buttons when clicked on it. How is this done? Is it a control? How is the buttons arranged?

Answer (score 1):

I am not certain what you are describing, perhaps post a picture if you can.

I think what you are looking for though is the [Android ActionBar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html)

Comment: On pre 3.0 devices take a look at Actionbar Sherlock -http://actionbarsherlock.com/download.html

Answer (score 0):

I am not getting you properly but i think you are talking about action bar as per your description as what you want. you can get the proper help from here

https://github.com/johannilsson/android-actionbar.

http://www.androidpatterns.com/uap_pattern/action-bar

hope you'll get some help..